# How to raise an exception that prints a message and returns a value?

Tags: exception, sml

Our professor asked us to do this in an assignment:

> If the threshold given is negative, you should print the message “Error: Negative Threshold” and return an empty list. To do this, deﬁne an exception called ThresholdOutOfRange, raise it if the threshold is negative, and handle the exception to achieve the proper behavior.

I don't understand how to raise an exception, return a value, and print an Error message. Right now my code for raising the exception is (just the important bits with the exception):

```
fun getnearbylist(center, threshold, ziplist) =
    let
      exception ThresholdOutOfRange;
      fun test_threshold(threshold, zip, nil) =nil
      |   test_threshold(threshold, zip, ziplist as x::xs) =
          if (threshold <0.0) then raise ThresholdOutOfRange
(*        [...skipped a long unrelated middle bit. most important is just knowing
              this function returns a string list...] *)
          else x::test_threshold(threshold, zip, xs)
    in
      test_threshold(threshold, center, ziplist)
      handle
      ThresholdOutOfRange => []
    end
```

So my code will just return an empty list when the exception is raised. Given that exceptions have to have the same return type as the function they're raised on to my knowledge, what could I do to be able to return the empty list and print an error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct that the resulting type of the exception handling must be the same as the expression you are handling the exception in. In other words, `exp_1` and `exp_2` must have the same type in the below code, just like the "then" and "else" part of an if-expression.

```
exp_1 handle pat => exp_2
```

So what you are looking for is a way of doing multiple things in the `exp_2` part, specifically something that has the side effect of printing a message. For such things you can use sequences. A sequence has the following form (note the parenthesis)

```
(exp_1; ... ; exp_n)
```

which itself is an expression. This is demonstrated in the following

```
- (print "foo\n"; print "bar\n"; 42);
foo
bar
val it = 42 : int
```

From this we can see that the end result of a sequence is what ever `exp_n` evaluates to.

Since sequences are often used in let-expressions, it is allowed to write the following (without the previous mentioned parenthesis)

```
let dec in exp_1 ; ... ; exp_n end
```

**Bonus info**

A sequence is actually a derived form (syntactic sugar) for a series of cases. The following

```
(expr_1 ; ... ; exp_n ; exp)
```

is equivalent to

```
case expr_1 of _ => 
  case ... =>
    case exp_n of _ => exp
```

Comment: I believe this is also referred to as `side-effecting`

Answer (score 1):

- First, declare an **exception**:

  > ```
  > exception OutOfRangeException;
  > ```
- define the function that will raise the exception :

  > ```
  > fun someFunc x =
  >   if x < 0 then 
  >     raise OutOfRangeException
  >   else [1,2,3,4] (*return some list*)
  > ```
- finally, the function that will handle the exception by printing a message and returning 
  and empty list:

> ```
> fun someFunc_test x=    
>   (someFunc x) handle OutOfRangeException => (print "exception"; [])
> ```

Comment: The exception doesn't need to be global. It just needs to be in scope of the code that handles it

Comment: well it is not necessarily good practice. There could be various reasons for keeping the exception hidden for the user. For example internal logic could be implemented by exception handling, and giving the user access to the exception could potentially screw it up. 

In general, as long as the exception is _only_ going to be used internally, there is no need to pollute the environment by declaring it "globally".

Comment: Exceptions are not slow in ML and friends, so unlike Java and others it may sometimes lead to an easy and beautiful way of handling control flow. I have for example seen a pretty neat solution to the [eight queen problem/puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) using exceptions for controlling control flow.